# duplicated .md pages on doxygen output

Tags: doxygen

I am producing the documentation with doxygen, and I have a tutorials tab where I have few pages links I produce in doxygen MarkupLanguage.

In my DoxygenLayout.xml I have the following

```
<tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="Tutorials" intro="Here ..." />
```

Then I have a directory in my doxygen folder named `../tutorials/`

I include that folder on my `doxygen.cfg`, and include `.md` files

```
INPUT = ../../source ../tutorials/

FILE_PATTERNS = *.cxx *.h *.md
```

The problem is if I specify inside the file tutorial1.md

```
\page tut_1 A first tutorial
```

The tutorials TAB will show 2 entries for that page. One with the name of the file (tutorial1) and another with the name of the page (A first tutorial).

What to do so that it only shows the entry "A first tutorial?"

If I do not specify the `\page` tag then I will have a single entry, but then I cannot reference to this page from other pages.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: My question is related to another question in stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151360/can-doxygen-process-pages-other-than-mainpage-dox

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but didn't succeed. Please post a reproducible example. Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: I was using version 1.8.6, what I got by default with my ubuntu distribution. I have downloaded the latest doxygen source with git clone, and compiled. I am now in version 1.8.14, the problem is not there anymore, thank you!